# JMeter / Jvm Load Testing

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, jvm

I'm currently load testing a system using Apache JMeter. I am interested in JVM properties, so I added a script to the server **-XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:"FILE_DESTINATION"** to get such informations.

I have three thread groups: 100, 500 and 1000 concurrent users.

1) I would like to know if it is a good idea deleting the content of the log file after each group execution or not, so each log reflects the JVM statistics of that group?

2) Is there a needed interval between one thread group execution and another ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would recommend restarting JVM between test executions, this way you will get more "clean" results without impact of previous tests
2. I believe point 1 answers your question. One tip: define reasonable `ramp-up` period in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) so the load could increase **gradually**. This way you will be able to correlate main [KPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_indicator)s with the increasing load. It is also a good idea to apply the same approach for `ramp-down`, this way you will be able to check if/how application recovers after the stress load.

---

You may also find [Perfmon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) useful, it is capable of collecting and plotting GC time and other [JMX metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) so you will get this information along with test results.

[image: JMeter JMX PerfMon]

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I adopted your solution :) What about a cluestered enviroment. Is it OK to use Jmeter calling a reverse proxy endpoint or maybe it is better to Call each node separately ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tomcat , add below content to setenv.sh file

```
-verbose:gc\
  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps\
  -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps\
  -XX:+PrintGCDetails\
  -XX:+PrintGC\
  -Xloggc:logs/gc-api.log\
  #-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution\  #optional 
  #-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime\   #optional
```